# SyntaxError: incomplete input как исправить?

Tags: python, изображения, pygame

Мой код:

```py
pygame.display.set_icon.load("C:\Users\Лука\Documents\ViberDownloads\sas")
```

Ошибка:

> SyntaxError: incomplete input

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `r-строку`, раз уж вы не экранируете бэкслэши:

```py
pygame.display.set_icon.load(r"C:\Users\Лука\Documents\ViberDownloads\sas")
                             ^
```